# Link to App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes, hyperlink

What's the link to my app on App Store? I want to input only the App ID.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"???"]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *idString = @"380886386";
NSString *countrtyString = @"us";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/%@/app/id%@?mt=8", countrtyString, idString]]];
```